# Stop application from exiting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm working on a Windows application (not WinForms, not Console, not WinService), is just a project with an entry class.
What is the best way, in .NET, to stop an application from exiting the Main method?

I know I can achieve this in console with Console.Read() or I can use EvenWaitHandle.WaitOne() and never call Set().

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE:**

This is an overview of the application.

I need to start independent processes (some exe) on demand, containing wcf service. WCF service should listen idefinetly and that is why I need this functionality. The most similar approach I can find is IIS (many w3wp processes running at the same time).

w3svc.exe (IIS windows service) starts many instances of w3wp.exe depending on the number of configured app pools and the requests, it receives.

In my application I want to keep up the processes representing w3wp.exe in the IIS infrastructure, not w3svc. What is the kind of message loop that would keep alive w3wp in .NET?

Comment: And what is the application actually doing?  Do you have another thread open doing work?  If so, just don't put it in another thread so that the main method doesn't end until the work is done (even if the work never finishes).

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan one too many `;` in the for loop, and those options are worse than just `WaitOne` or `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Exactly. I have a a wcf service running on it. It cannot be a windows service because I need to have many of the same processes running (exe) at the same time and start them also on demand or shut them down.

Comment: @Servy  Fixed and I agree.  Just listing options :).

Comment: I have a windows service managing these processes. But the processes should keep listening unles the service shuts the process down. Shutting the process down is not related in any way on finishing any task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS is a windows service which is why it runs like this. You might look at other options like a single service where you can invoke it via an api and tell it to start another thread or listener. Starting new instances of applications isn't the best option. Typically windows applications have a messagepump, which is a while loop I think...which would prevent it from exiting.

However, you can also follow the example here, which I believe does not close the formless window:

[Run Formless Notification User Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605577/run-formless-notification-user-control)

Comment: i know IIS is a windows service, but not all the w3wp.exe instances that you see in the task manager. These are started by w3svc.exe (IIS) I want to achieve the same. what kind of message pump is running inside w3wp? That is the real question.

Comment: just use the standard windows message pump...it's just an efficient while loop. I believe if you follow the link I posted it'll have what you need to do that, since I think windows forms just run right on top and hide the pump from you.

Comment: Your link makes sense. let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do that in sooo many ways. I personally like this one, as it is very readable and self explanatory:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{
    // to make it less CPU intensive
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Of course, any solution you can think of will not prevent the forceful termination of application by killing its process.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisenconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update you say that the program is starting several other programs using Process. (It happens to be 'yourself' but that doesn't matter.)

If the program has already done that it doesn't sound like it has any more to do.  That process ending won't kill all of the processes it spawned.

You can use the `process.WaitForExit()` to wait for the processes that you spawn to all exit, rather than just spinning doing nothing, if for some reason you really need to keep the process alive.  If there is something that it actually needs to do after spawning the other processes then you'd need to tell us what that is, because if there is something you should be waiting on an event of some sort, which is something you haven't brought up.

Edit: you claim that all the process is doing is "listening".  Define that task.  If you have a blocking GetNextRequest method then you simply have: `while(true){GetNextRequest();}`.  If it's non blocking, then use use a `BlockingCollection<MyRequests>` in which the receive method/event hanlder adds a new item to the collection and the main thread had a while loop just like I mentioned before reading from the blocking collection.  The point is that you shouldn't ever just sit there and do nothing; you process is doing something, so do that in a `while(!done)` or `while(true)` loop.  If the method isn't blocking, it's a reasonably well defined problem to solve; just wrap it in a blocking method call.

Comment: Again, these processes host wcf services. They are listeners, they need to be up indefinetly. I dont want them to exit, I want them to keep listening. What is WaitForExit waiting on? a piece of work? or is there a signal to shut it down?

Comment: You say that your program is spawning other processes, presumably using the `Process` class.  You can wait on those processes if you need to wait.  If you are talking about the worker processes, not the process spawning them, then are there no blocking calls for the listening methods?

Comment: I gues I'm not being clear. I want to know how to never exit the Main method of each one  of these processes (exe). I'm not worried about the program spawning my processes because it is a windows service, this i know it will run forever unless I stop the windows service. I'm woried abouth the ones that are not windows services that are being started by my windows service and that I want for them to be up forever unless I kill them.

Comment: The point is that if a process is doing nothing but sitting there in a Thread.Sleep it's clearly not doing anything and might as well just die.  If it's actually doing something, we need to know the specifics of what you're doing to tell you how to ensure that it won't finish until it's actually done.  By just ignoring the whole 'what it actually does' part you prevent us from giving any meaningful answer.

Comment: It is listening for calls (WCF Service Host). That is what they are doing, listening. I want to have all these WCF listeners running in different process because of application requirements. The easiest question would be: How do you run a ServiceHost on a console application and stop the console application from reaching the end of Main method so your ServiceHost can listen forever. I know you have Console.Read() for console applications. What do you have for a more elavorated application that doesn't need a black window on the screen?

Comment: And there are an infinite number of ways in which they can go about the task of "listening".  I have asked you several times to clarify and expand on that, maybe even post the relevant section of code *gasp*.  If you don't want to be helped then I guess there's nothing more for me to do.